# IPv6 "Activation of network connecting failed" [WiFi] and many urls unreachable (incl snap)

Tags: networking, dns, snap, ipv6, ipv4

The first thing I noticed was that snap could not connect (running release 22.10):

> Failed to find refreshable snaps: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=cannot list updates: persistent network error: Post "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp 185.125.188.59:443: connect: network is unreachable

Then I tried to look for help online, but with Firefox and Chromium I could only access some websites (google.com, heise.de...), but not e.g. askubuntu.com

After rebooting the computer I could not connect to my WiFi:

> Activation of network connecting failed

Disabling ipv6 did not solve this problem, but disabling ipv4 did.

But I was still only able to connect to some websites. I tried several alternative DNS servers (e.g. Google). Still no solution.

I also checked if any proxies are set, but no.

I would be happy about any suggestions!

I forgot to mention that our ISP sent a new router. All other computers have no problems with the new device and can still connect to domains that do not support IPv6. The Ubuntu computer, however, only allows me to connect to the router when I disable IPv4.
Thank you

Comment: Could this be a router setting? Did you maybe turn off IP6 or IP4 support in the router?

Comment: Thank you! Now I have a solution. I had to active both IPv6 and IPv4. But in IPv4 I had manually add a DNS server (I put 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

Comment: While that may work as a fallback, your internet provider should give you access to a couple of DNS servers.